# Pythonic way to encapsulate method arguments of a class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

Objects of my class A are similar to network connections, i.e. characterized by a handle per connection opened. That is, one calls different methods with a handle (a particular connection) as argument. My class A (python 2.7) looks like:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    ... some init
  def my_open(self, *args)
    handle = ... some open
    return handle
  def do_this(self, handle, *args):
    foo_this(handle, args)
  def do_that(self, handle, *args):
    foo_that(handle, args)
```

A typical usage is

```
a = A(args)
handle = a.my_open(args2)
a.do_this(handle, args3)
```

Now, in a particular situation, there is only one connection to take care of, i.e. one handle in play. So, it is reasonable to hide this handle but keep class A for the more general situation. Thus, my first thoughts on a class B
which "is a" kind of class A (usage stays the same but hides handle) are:

```
class B(A):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    super(A, self).__init__(args)
    self.handle = None
  def my_open(self, *args):
    self.handle = super(A, self).__init__(args)
  def do_this(self, *args):
    super(A, self).do_this(self.handle, args)
  def do_that(self, *args):
    super(A, self).do_that(self.handle, args)
```

Unfortunately, in my opinion, it seems very convoluted. Any better ideas?

Comment: For consistency sake, I'd **just return that one handle**, and make it a singleton.

Comment: And really, you need to put the methods `do_this()` and `do_that()` *on the handle object*. That means: `handle = a.my_open(args2)`, then `handle.do_this(args3)`.

Comment: Your system built so that you can open a handle with one A object and use it with another or use the first A with another handle. It is a mess as for me. Make it more organized.

Answer (score 1):

> Objects of my class A are similar to network connections, i.e. characterized by a handle per connection opened. That is, one calls different methods with a handle (a particular connection) as argument.

You have inverted the responsibility. The `handle` object holds the state the methods operate on, so those methods should live on the handle, not the factory.

Move your methods to the handle object, so the API becomes:

```
a = A(args)
handle = a.my_open(args2)
handle.do_this(args3)
```

The class implementing the `handle()` could retain a reference to `a` if so required; that's an implementation detail that the users of the API don't need to worry about.

You then return new handles, *or* a singleton handle, as needed.

By moving responsibility to the handle object, you can also make your factory produce handles of entirely different types, depending on the arguments. `A(args).my_open(args2)` could also produce the singleton handle that you now have class `B` for, for example.

Answer (score 0):

How about a class for the `handle` itself?:

```
class Handle(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # init ...
        self._handle = low_level_handle
    def do_this(self, *args):
        # do_this ...
        pass
    def do_that(self, *args):
        # do_that
        pass

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
       # init ...
    def my_open(self, *args):
       handle = Handle(args)
       # handle post-processing (if any)
       return handle
```

e.g.:

```
a = A(args)
handle = a.my_open(args2)
handle.do_this(args3)
```